# Como puedo compilar/obtener el bytecode de este proyecto de ethereum

Tags: json

Hola hice esta pregunta en ethereum pero no me hicieron mucho caso.

etherdelta.sol

```
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"name":"expires","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"trade","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"name":"expires","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"}],"name":"order","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"orderFills","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"name":"expires","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"cancelOrder","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"token","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"depositToken","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"name":"expires","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"amountFilled","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"tokens","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"feeMake_","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeFeeMake","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeMake","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"feeRebate_","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeFeeRebate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeAccount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"name":"expires","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"sender","type":"address"}],"name":"testTrade","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"feeAccount_","type":"address"}],"name":"changeFeeAccount","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeRebate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"feeTake_","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeFeeTake","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"admin_","type":"address"}],"name":"changeAdmin","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"token","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdrawToken","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"orders","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeTake","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"accountLevelsAddr_","type":"address"}],"name":"changeAccountLevelsAddr","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"accountLevelsAddr","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"token","type":"address"},{"name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"admin","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"name":"expires","type":"uint256"},{"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"name":"user","type":"address"},{"name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"availableVolume","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"admin_","type":"address"},{"name":"feeAccount_","type":"address"},{"name":"accountLevelsAddr_","type":"address"},{"name":"feeMake_","type":"uint256"},{"name":"feeTake_","type":"uint256"},{"name":"feeRebate_","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"payable":false,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"expires","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"Order","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"expires","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"nonce","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Cancel","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenGet","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amountGet","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokenGive","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amountGive","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"get","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"give","type":"address"}],"name":"Trade","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"user","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdraw","type":"event"}]
```

reservetoken.sol

```
[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"minter","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"account","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"create","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"account","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"destroy","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]
```

token.sol

```
[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"supply","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]
```

La pregunta es como conseguir el bytecode de los smart contracts. Segui el consejo de instalar truffle pero no se como compilar los smart contracts.

Aqui es donde abri pero no consegui una solucion.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55840/how-to-make-installation-of-etherdelta-smart-contract

Alguien podria orientarme o darme una idea como instalar el smart contract o como compilarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar dos comandos consecutivamente en la terminal:

1. truffle compile // Esto compila el contrato
2. truffle migrate // Esto lo sube a la blockchain

(Importante) Antes debes indicar el nodo (local / remoto) en que quieres hacer el deploy (archivo de configuración de Truffle). Yo para pruebas uso Ganache que es muy cómodo.